# React Redux Proper way of iterating over data on init

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a form in React where users can see data (returned via async on load) and edit it inline. If I navigate to the form from another page via a link, the form works as expected as the data is loaded before the main render function, however, if I refresh the page with the form on it, the data isn't populated properly despite it coming through in props.

So: 
`Initial render with loading div -> Data comes back -> Props set -> Render fires -> State is set`

Since the inputs on the form have initial values set from `this.state`, they're blank on the second render. However, if I navigate here from another page, everything works as you would expect. It seems like I'm missing something regarding React/Redux.

Here's the bottom presentation component:

```
class ContactInfoForm extends React.Component {
    constructor (props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.state = Object.assign({}, props.contactInfo);

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    }

    render () {
        const {
            contactInfo
        } = this.props;

        console.log(this.state); // {} - first render {} - second render
        console.log(this.props); // {} - first render {stuff} - second render

        return (
            <form>
                <div className="col-xs-12"> 
                    <TextInputGroup
                        name="email"
                        value={this.state.email}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        floatedLabel="Email/Username"
                        placeholder="Email/Username"
                        className="AccountPreferences__field"
                        labelClass="AccountPreferences__label"
                    />
                </div>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

I understand that `setState` is asynchronous so this makes sense, but I'm wondering what is the best way to initialize a form in React/Redux.

Comment: For reference, I've been following React's guide on Forms: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: you are facing the issue when refreshing the page correct ?

Comment: Correct. Navigation from other pages works fine. `this.state` isn't set on load after the promise comes back and the component re-renders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method it will get called whenever any change happens to props values so at that time you need to update the state value.

Use this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
    this.setState(newProps.contactInfo);
}
```

**[componentWillReceiveProps:](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)**

> componentWillReceiveProps() is invoked before a mounted component
>   receives new props. If you need to update the state in response to
>   prop changes (for example, to reset it), you may compare this.props
>   and nextProps and perform state transitions using this.setState() in
>   this method.

Comment: Looks like this works, however, I'm now getting `TextInputGroup is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled`. Do I need to specify the properties when I create `this.state` in the constructor? (Line 5, instead of using an empty object)

Comment: you can do that also, define all in state variable, or simply do this: `value={this.state.email || ""}` put a **|| "" (blank value)**. Reason is initially this.state.email will be undefined when refreshing the page so it will became a uncontrolled component, providing a default blank value will make it controlled component.